# Dual Boot Ubuntu on HDD and Windows on SDD, tried installing but grub not working

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, gpt, secure-boot

I have an SSD of 256GB with Windows 10 installed in it. I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 on HDD. I tried installing it on HDD  by creating /, /boot, /home , EFI partitions ( I was unable to install Ubuntu without creating the EFI partition). Also, I selected the "default drive to install the bootloader" as the `/dev/sda6` which was (EFI's partition).

But, I couldn't get the boot options to choose between Windows and Ubuntu.
Tried executing `sudo os-prober`, nothing showed up. I deleted all the partitions from windows and tried installing it again in the Windows EFI partition.

This time, I found out that, the Windows EFI partition(`/dev/sda1` in this case) was not mentioned in the "default drive to install the bootloader".

My system is a UEFI, GPT enabled. with secure boot on.

Could you please provide any inputs on how to install Ubuntu on my HDD and get a grub menu while booting up.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: could you add a screenshot of partition table and I recommend turning secure boot off. you can read this : https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/disable-secure-uefi-dual-boot/

Comment: I have added an image of partitions, sorry the image is not so clear. Thanks.

Comment: I am no expert myself but I think the SSD should be in `/dev/sdax` format and HDD should be in `/dev/sdbx` however that is not the case here. And you made a swap partition which is actually not required these days because Linux now use a "swap file" but if you like partition it's alright. Next you have 2 `ext4` partition with no mount points. mount `/` and `/home` if you want to. What was the error when you try to install without `efi` partition

Comment: I don't know that we needn't make a swap partition. But the error without EFI partition was "No EFI system partition was found, the system will likely not be able to boot successfully and the installation may fail". Then I created a FAT32 format EFI partition ( I found this in the community post). Actually, there should be a windows EFI partition (which is 'unknown' in this case), it is not detected by the linux partition table.

Comment: may i know the laptop or desktop you are using. In some cases the grub does not pop-up by itself. You might need to choose OS by pressing `F9` or your system specific bootmenu key to choose the OS. Try to install the OS and try boot from boot menu and did you turn off the secure boot?

Comment: It's a Dell G7. Yeah, I used to press 'F12', to choose Windows or Ubunut. The options present in it are Windows Boot Manager and Ubuntu. But, I wanted a pop up to be displayed. Currently, I am looking at  rEFInd, a bootloader manager to install. That might be able to recognize to EFI partitions installed. I my case, the grub is not detecting windows, and I don't want to mess with windows boot manager to add linux into it. So, the two different entities Windows EFI and Ubuntus EFI which are in different drives (SSD, HDD) are to be recognized by a single bootmanager (Either grub or rEFInd).

Comment: I see, so your Ubuntu works fine and windows too but your grub doesn't load to let you choose the OS during boot. Can you tell me which OS loads by default. i have never worked with SSD myself but in HDD the bootloader should be at the first track of the disk platter for it to load and grub goes there along with windows bootloader to let you choose from them. Since you got 2 bootloade both at different place I don't think it will ever give you a chance to choose an OS becz the files required to boot the other OS is at different place.

Comment: I think you might need to remove either one of them and install the bootloader of both OS at one place for you to get a menu

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this software, it cleaned every problem I had before with the GRUB stuff.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Install the software:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then run it and follow the instructions according to your problem:

```
$ boot-repair
```

I hope it helps, and welcome!

(Please try the solution before voting it as answer)

Comment: Thanks, Shall I install Ubuntu by creating  /, /home, EFI partitions on HDD and using 'dev/sda6' (ubuntu's EFI partitions drive) as the "default bootloader to install ubuntu"? Before trying the above solutions to show windows 10 on grub bootloader.